# array.push() method throwing TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to implement `array.map()` using `array.reduce()`. Here's what I have so far:

```
function arrayMap(arr, fn) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a, elem) {
        return a.push(fn(elem));
    }, []);
}

let x = arrayMap([1, 2, 3], function(elem) {
    return elem * 2;
});

console.log(x);
```

But the interpreter is giving me:

> TypeError: a.push is not a function

Even though the accumulator `'a'` is provided to reduce as an empty array.

Comment: This isn't really a good use case for `reduce`, here, as your "accumulator" is the same from start to finish. As you notice you got lost in the useless complexity. Using `forEach` would be cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method returns the length of the array and you are returning the length. So in the next iteration,  `a` would be a number(`1`) not the array.

To make it work you need to return the array reference instead.

```
function arrayMap(arr, fn) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a, elem) {
        a.push(fn(elem));
        return  a;
    }, []);
}
```

```js
function arrayMap(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, elem) {
    a.push(fn(elem));
    return a;
  }, []);
}

let x = arrayMap([1, 2, 3], function(elem) {
  return elem * 2;
});

console.log(x);
```

---

Actually, the [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method making it over complex a far better idea would be to use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method instead.

```
function arrayMap(arr, fn) {
    return arr.map(fn);
}
```

```js
function arrayMap(arr, fn) {
  return arr.map(fn);
}
let x = arrayMap([1, 2, 3], function(elem) {
  return elem * 2;
});

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead.

```
function arrayMap(arr, fn) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a, elem) {
        return a.concat(fn(elem));
    }, []);
}

let x = arrayMap([1, 2, 3], function(elem) {
    return elem * 2;
});

console.log(x); // [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter `currentIndex` of [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which is the index of the current element being processed in the array. Starts at index 0, if an initialValue is provided, and at index 1 otherwise.

```js
function arrayMap(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, elem, currentIndex) {
    a[currentIndex] = fn(elem);
    return a;
  }, []);
}

let x = arrayMap([1, 2, 3], function(elem) {
  return elem * 2;
});

console.log(x);
```